# Print 2D list by columns(rotation) to console C#

Tags: c#, list, rotation, console-application

I have some list of lists that I want to print to a console by the columns.
The List looks like this.

```
List<List<string>> my2DimList = new List<List<string>>();
```

Then in some loop I iterate and add some `chars`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
    my2DimList.Add(new List<string>());
}

for (int i = 0; i < numLoops; i++)
{
    //Do some work here
    my2DimList[s].Add(my_char);    
}
```

I want to print the `chars` to the console In the following way.

 If the list holds 2 lists that hold:

```
Jon
Mike
```

then I want to print it like this:

```
 e
nk
oi
JM
```

What is the best approach to do that? 
I've thought of some rotation but the lists are not the same length

Comment: @Media I'ts illustrated in the end of my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's get the preliminaries out of the way:

```
var list = new List<List<string>> 
    { 
        new List<string> { "J", "o", "n" }, 
        new List<string> { "M", "i", "k", "e"} 
    };

int h = list.Count;
int w = list.Max(l => l.Count);
```

So first, let's take a look at what the regular printing method would look like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < w; j++)
    {
        if (j < list[i].Count)
            Console.Write(list[i][j]);
        else
            Console.Write(" ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}

// Prints:
// Jon
// Mike
```

Now you want to print it in columns, so let's switch the order of the `for` headers:

```
for (int j = 0; j < w; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        if (j < list[i].Count)
            Console.Write(list[i][j]);
        else
            Console.Write(" ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}

// Prints:
// JM
// oi
// nk
//  e
```

And now you want to print it from the bottom up rather than from the top down. For that, when we count for our vertical index, we start at the max and count down instead of starting at the min and counting up:

```
for (int j = w - 1; j >= 0; j--)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        if (j < list[i].Count)
            Console.Write(list[i][j]);
        else
            Console.Write(" ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}

// Prints:
//  e
// nk
// oi
// JM
```

And there you have it. Printing strings in particular orders is just a series of reversals.

Comment: I am being told that operator < can't be applied to operand of type int and method group. What am I doing wrong? Also, can't apply indexing with [] to an expression of type "items". "items" is the name of my list that I got from a dbcontext by doing a ToList() on it.

Comment: @Spero `Count` is the length property of `List`, but it is also a LINQ method for enumerables in general. If you can't use an indexer or call the `Count` property of your list variable, then chances are that it isn't actually a `List` but some other kind of enumerable.